# How to use XCCONFIG in XCode 8.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcconfig

I have a set of variables that changes depending on the environment (debug and release) in which it is running.

I have created three xcconfig files (common, debug and release), see below the content from each file.

**Common.xcconfig**

```
BACKEND_URL = https:\/\/www.mydomain.com.br\/api\/v1\/test
```

**Debug.xcconfig**

```
#include "Common.xcconfig"

BACKEND_URL = http:\/\/10.32.112.107:8080\/api\/v1\/test
```

**Release.xcconfig**

```
#include "Common.xcconfig"
```

I would like to display on the screen the contents of the variable according to the environment and I do not know where to configure in the build to use these files.

Comment: This url help me a lot:
https://awesomeswift.com/2016/04/11/using-xcconfig-files-for-your-xcode-project.swift

Comment: This url help me too: https://hackernoon.com/a-cleaner-way-to-organize-your-ios-debug-development-and-release-distributions-6b5eb6a48356

Comment: The link is no longer working on the comment. Can you please help me how to use this file in swift?????

Comment: The second link still work,

Comment: Thanks yes I checked it later